# Warum steht in diesem Satz „eines“ statt „eins“?

Tags: pronoun, gender

Im folgenden Satz, der richtig sein muss, verstehe ich nicht, warum das Wort in fetter Schrift gewählt wurde:

> (…) des 19. Jahrhunderts war **eines** der wichtigsten Ereignisse in
>   der Musik in dieser Zeit.

Ich hätte *eins* stattdessen geschrieben, weil *eins* für „das Ereignis“ steht.

- Warum eines?
- Stünde anstelle des Substantivs *Ereignis* ein feminines oder maskulines Substantiv, sollte es dann *eine* bzw. *einer* (wie in folgendem Beispiel) heißen?

> (…) des 19. Jahrhunderts war **{eine · einer}** der wichtigsten {Tragödien · Meilensteine} in
>   der Musik in dieser Zeit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guckst du [hier](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein#Indefinitpronomen)!

Sowohl *eines* als auch *eins* sind möglich. Der Autor hat sich möglicherweise für *eines* entschieden, weil es ein höheres Sprachregister ausdrücken soll.